# Mass Printing on Generic Inquiry

Tags: printing, customization, acumatica

I have created a generic inquiry in Acumatica that returns work orders that are open. We know that there is a print action that can be applied however, we want to print out multiple instances of the work orders. So we do not have to print them individually. Is there currently a solution for mass printing or can someone point me in the right direction of maybe a work around? I know there is a mass action print all function that can be found however, it does not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Just like in any other action redirecting users to the generated report(s), the **Service Orders' Print Service Order** button throws a `PXReportRequiredException` to open generated report in new window:

```
public class ServiceOrderEntry : PXGraph<ServiceOrderEntry, FSServiceOrder>
{
    ...
    public PXAction<FSServiceOrder> printServiceOrder;

    [PXUIField]
    [PXButton]
    public virtual void PrintServiceOrder()
    {
        if (this.IsDirty) Actions.PressSave();
        if (ServiceOrderRecords.Current == null) return;

        Dictionary<string, string> serviceOrderParameters = 
            GetServiceOrderParameters(ServiceOrderRecords.Current, false);
        if (serviceOrderParameters.Count != 0)
        {
            throw new PXReportRequiredException(serviceOrderParameters, 
                "SD641000", PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow, string.Empty);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

If you add **Service Orders' Print Service Order** action as a mass action to Generic Inquiry (as shown on the screenshots below), the GI mass action will generate and open Service Order report form only for the first selected Service Order. Processing of any consequent Service Order will not be possible due to the `PXReportRequiredException` thrown to show the report form generated for the first Service Order.
[image]
[image]

In order to merge Service Order report forms generated for several Service Orders into a single report, you should create a custom processing screen and use the **AddSibling** method on a **PXReportRequiredException** instance. The **AddSibling** method will append the reports generated for 2nd+ Service Order to the **PXReportRequiredException** instance initially created for the first processed Service Order. After all selected Service Orders has been processed, a single `PXReportRequiredException` will be thrown to redirect the user to Report Viewer displaying all generated reports at once.

```
public class PrintServiceOrderProcess : PXGraph<PrintServiceOrderProcess>
{
    public PXCancel<FSServiceOrder> Cancel;
    public PXProcessing<FSServiceOrder> ServiceOrderRecords;

    public PrintServiceOrderProcess()
    {
        ServiceOrderRecords.SetProcessDelegate(list => PrintServiceOrders(list));
    }

    public static void PrintServiceOrders(IEnumerable<FSServiceOrder> list)
    {
        PXReportRequiredException ex = null;
        foreach (var order in list)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            string srvOrdType = SharedFunctions
                .GetFieldName<FSServiceOrder.srvOrdType>(true);
            string refNbr = SharedFunctions
                .GetFieldName<FSServiceOrder.refNbr>(true);
            parameters[srvOrdType] = order.SrvOrdType;
            parameters[refNbr] = order.RefNbr;

            if (ex == null)
            {
                ex = new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, "SD641000", "SD641000");
            }
            else
            {
                ex.AddSibling("SD641000", parameters, false);
            }
        }
        if (ex != null) throw ex;
    }
}
```